# how to access and work with a single bit in function that gets the parameter as void * type?

Tags: c, pointers, bit, void

I need to count how many '1' bits there are in some kind of numeric parameter (unknown type). the function that counts the bits gets a void *.
how can I access each bit when I don't know the type of the parameter?

*******edit*******
I get an array of an unknown type of parameters and need to count all the lit bits in all cells. what I'm trying to do, but won't work:

```
int my_count(void *arr[],int size){
    int i=0,j=0,lit_bits=0,size_each_cell=0;
    unsigned char *ptr=(char*)arr;
    size_each_cell= sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(j=0;j<NUM_OF_BITS*size_each_cell;j++){
            if(ptr[j]==1){
                lit_bits++;
            }
            ptr=ptr+1;
        }
    }
    return lit_bits;
}

int main(){
    int size,i;
    int arr[SIZE_OF_ARRAY]={1,0,0,1,1,2,3};
    printf("number of lit bits is: %d",my_count(arr,SIZE_OF_ARRAY));
}
```

Comment: `void *` has no way to know what type it points to, so you have to pass that information to the function separately.

Comment: `size_each_cell= sizeof(arr[0]);` is not valid C (but works in GCC, Clang!), what you really want is `sizeof (ptr[0])` - but it is of type unsigned char, and the sizeof that is 1.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala actually no, I want the size of each byte in the array... and for examle, if I'm sending an array of ints the output if 4 as expected. I want to go through a total of (byte size * 8 bits) bits to count all the lit one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm calculating it inside the function.

Comment: @ValentinaNikolenko a size of a byte is **one**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala sure, but I'm checking how many bytes there are in one cell of the array... (array of ints, has in each cell 4 bytes so ill get the answer 4)

Comment: No, you're not doing that. Since `arr[0]` is `void *`, `sizeof(arr[0])` is equal to `sizeof(void *)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access bits then the type of the object isn’t very important. What *is* important, however, is its size. You need to know that in order to know how many bits to read.

So you need to pass that into the function:

```
int bitcount(void *obj, size_t size) {
    const unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *) obj;
    int total_bits = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        total_bits += count_bits_in_byte(buffer[i]);
    }
    return total_bits;
}
```

Here `count_bits_in_byte` is a standard bit-counting function for a single byte, e.g. using naive counting, or a lookup table, or some variation thereof (using `char` might be OK but `unsigned char` is less trouble since `unsigned` types have well-defined integer overflow semantics).

Comment: You could do `char *buffer = (char *)obj;` to avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: " the type of the object isn’t very important" -- best to stick with unsigned integer types because eventually you'll try to do something tricky and sign extension will bite you.

Comment: Somehow unrelated but is `char buffer[size]` equivalent to a `malloc()` followed by an automatic `free()` when it goes out of scope?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Of course, yes! I used `memcpy` to avoid strict aliasing issues but then pivoted to using `char` so obviously the aliasing issue is moot. Either way the copy is probably optimised out (but I haven’t checked).

Comment: @Matthieu Not quite. It’s a stack-allocated variable-length array. It’s roughly equivalent to using `alloca`, however.

Answer (score 0):

managed to solve the problem, here is a working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_OF_BITS 8
#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY 8

int my_count(void *arr,int length_array,int size_in_bytes){
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,lit_bits=0;
    const unsigned char *ptr=arr;
    for (i=0 ; i<length_array ; i++){
        for(j=0;j<size_in_bytes;j++,ptr++){
            for (k = 0; k <NUM_OF_BITS; k++) {
                if( *ptr & (1<<k)){
                    lit_bits++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return lit_bits;
}

int main(){
    int size_in_bytes;
    int arr[SIZE_OF_ARRAY]={1,0,0,1,1,2,3,7};
    size_in_bytes= sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("number of lit bits is: %d",my_count(arr,SIZE_OF_ARRAY,size_in_bytes));
}
```